# Dropdown menu with jQuery and nth-child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I just made a dropdown menu with jQuery and a little bit
special html structure.
This is how my structure looks like.
[image]
And this is the jsFiddle, which was created: https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/10/
But I want it to work like a proper dropdown menu. So that means it should show the submenu_link when you hover over the menu. f.e. if you hover over the menu_link q, the the submenu_link 1-5 should dropdown.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.menu_link').ready(function () {
    $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
  });
  $('.menu_link').hover(function () {
    $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown(200);
  });
  $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').mouseenter( function () {
    $(this).show();
  });
  $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $('.menu_link').mouseleave(function () {
    $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
  });
});
```

And this is my ASP.NET code:

```
<nav id="menu">

  <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubmenu" runat="server">
     
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                          
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>                  
          
  </asp:Panel>
</nav>
```

Can i do this with the nth-child anyhow?
I would also like the have the links in a list style how can I do that?

Comment: Why are you using `<div>` rather than `<ul> <li>` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution i found with your markup.

Used CSS to beautify it.

**Jquery:**
What did you do?
when `.menu_link` is hovered i find what index it has.
The index finds if its the first child or second etc.
When we have this magic index number **`var nthNumber`**
we can use it to find its corresponding `.submenu_panel` (I'm guessing here since i cant see all your code) and hide or show this panel

Eg. when we hover the **first** `.menu_link`,
we will show the **first** `.submenu_panel`
And we do the same for the second and third etc.

```js
$(".menu_link, .submenu_panel").hover(function() {
  //Hover inn function
  var nthNumber = $(this).index() + 1;

  $("[id$=Submenu]").show();
  $("[id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel:nth-of-type(" + nthNumber + ")").show();
}, function() {
  //Hover out function
  $("[id$=Submenu]").hide();
  var nthNumber = $(this).index() + 1;
  $("[id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel:nth-of-type(" + nthNumber + ")").hide();
});
```

```css
#menu [id$=Menu] {
  border: 2px solid #2980b9;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3498db;
}
#menu [id$=Menu] .menu_link {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#menu [id$=Menu] .menu_link:hover {
  background-color: #45a9ec;
  //border: 2px solid #2980b9;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer; //Visual only (REMOVE)!
}
#menu [id$=Submenu] {
  display: none;
}
#menu [id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel {
  display: none;
  background-color: #45a9ec;
  border: 2px solid #2980b9;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
#menu [id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel .submenu_link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 15px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 4px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2980b9;
}
#menu [id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel .submenu_link:hover {
  background-color: #56bafd;
  cursor: pointer; //ONLY FOR VISUAL(REMOVE)!
}
#menu [id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel .submenu_link:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #2980b9;
  margin-top: -5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu">
  <div id="pn1Menu">
    <a class="menu_link">Lorem</a>
    <a class="menu_link">Ipsum</a>
    <a class="menu_link">Dollar</a>
    <a class="menu_link">Si</a>
    <a class="menu_link">Amet</a>
  </div>
  <div id="pn1Submenu">
    <div class="submenu_panel">
      <a class="submenu_link">100</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">200</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">300</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">400</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">500</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">600</a>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu_panel">
      <a class="submenu_link">010</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">020</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">030</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">040</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">050</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">060</a>
    </div>
    <div class="submenu_panel">
      <a class="submenu_link">1001</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">2002</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">3003</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">4004</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">5005</a>
      <a class="submenu_link">6006</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It does almost work, but as you can see in th jsFiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/13/), if I hover for the first time it shows the submenu from menu1 and menu2 and if I go on th menu2 it only shows the one for menu2 and if i go back on the menu1 it only shows the submenu1 as it should.

Comment: @aha364636, you can add this line to @Persjin's code: `$("[id$=Submenu] .submenu_panel").hide();` to initially hide all submenus. Insert it before this line `$("[id$=Submenu]").show();`. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/15/)

Comment: @aha364636 i spent a lot of time to make this look good and be able to work with your code. I cant make it perfectly as you want it. Some you will have to modify your self, and if you are going to use my code you have to understand it. And as Frank points out it seems like you only need to make small changes to make it work.

Comment: @FrankFajardo I'm sorry, I don't have a big knowledge of jQuery so I couldn't find out what I forgot, your fiddle saved the question.

Answer (score 4):

i tweaked quite a bit https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/19/  You will have to try it out with a real page to know for sure.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.menu_link').ready(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
     });
     $('.menu_link1').hover(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown(200);
         $("[class$=submenu_panel]").css("left", "0px");
     });
     $('.menu_link2').hover(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown(200);
         $("[class$=submenu_panel]").css("left", "12%");
         
     });
     $('.menu_link3').hover(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown(200);
         $("[class$=submenu_panel]").css("left", "25%");
     });
     $('.menu_link4').hover(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown(200);
        $("[class$=submenu_panel]").css("left", "37%");
     });
     $('.menu_link5').hover(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown(200);
         $("[class$=submenu_panel]").css("left", "50%");
     });
     $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').mouseenter(function () {
         $(this).show();
     });
     $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').mouseleave(function () {
         $(this).hide();
     });
     $('.menu_link1').mouseleave(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
     });
      $('.menu_link2').mouseleave(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
     });
      $('.menu_link3').mouseleave(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
     });
      $('.menu_link4').mouseleave(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
     });
      $('.menu_link5').mouseleave(function () {
         $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
     });
     });
```

```css
#pnlMenu .menu_link:hover #pnlSubmenu .submenu_link {
    height:50px;
    display:block;
}
#wrapper_menu {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#menuicon {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 27px;
    display: none;
}
.menubar {
    background: #001155;
    height: 4px;
    width: 27px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
#menuicon:hover #menubar-top {
    transform: translate(0px, 9px) rotate(45deg);
}
#menuicon:hover #menubar-mid {
    opacity: 0;
}
#menuicon:hover #menubar-bottom {
    transform: translate(0px, -9px) rotate(-45deg);
}
#menu {
    height: 44px;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95)), color-stop(100%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#c1c0c2', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
#pnlMenu {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.menu_link1, .menu_link2, .menu_link3, .menu_link4, .menu_link5, .menu_link6 {
    position:relative;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 44px;
    padding: 0 40px;
    text-align:left;
}
.menu_link1:active, .menu_link2:active, .menu_link3:active, .menu_link4:active, .menu_link5:active, .menu_link6:active, .menu_link1:focus, .menu_link2:focus, .menu_link3:focus, .menu_link4:focus, .menu_link5:focus, .menu_link6:focus, {
    color: #2d98e5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgb(229, 229, 229);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95)), color-stop(100%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95)) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(193, 192, 194, 0.95) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.95) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(endColorstr='#c1c0c2', startColorstr='#e5e5e5', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
.last_menu_link {
    float: right;
}
.submenu_link {
}
.submenu_panel {
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
    background: gray;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper_menu">
    <div id="menuicon">
        <div class="menubar" id="menubar-top"></div>
        <div class="menubar" id="menubar-mid"></div>
        <div class="menubar" id="menubar-bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <nav id="menu">
        <div id="pnlMenu"> <a class="menu_link1" href="Index.aspx?category=1">menu1</a><a class="menu_link2" href="Index.aspx?category=2">menu2</a><a class="menu_link3" href="Index.aspx?category=4">menu3</a><a class="menu_link4" href="Index.aspx?category=5">menu4</a><a class="menu_link5" href="Index.aspx?category=6">menu5</a><a class="menu_link6 last_menu_link" href="Index.aspx?category=8">menu6</a>

        </div>
        <div id="pnlSubmenu" style="display:none">
            <div class="submenu_panel" style="height:100px"> <a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=7">submenu1</a><a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=8">submenu2</a>

            </div>
            <div class="submenu_panel" style="height:100px"> <a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=4">Link1</a>
 <a class="submenu_link" href="Pages/Chart.aspx?id=11">Link2</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you also do something to the CSS, or how did you do it to only show it, where you hover? I would like to connect Persijn's answer with yours.

Comment: But which CSS or jQuery does make that it's only displayed under the exact link you hover?

Comment: its in the jquery the line under the slide down i set a left

Comment: Oh now I got it, but this is gonna be difficult to add to the code from Persijn.

Comment: @RachelGallen nice solution :) One problem, you cant press any of the links since they disappear when you try to hoover over them.

Comment: @Persijn yes i noticed that after posting. I was focused on trying to position them correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for? 
Use CSS rather than jquery. This should get you started.

https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/bgryLLwo/

HTML

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Link
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>Example 1</li>
            <li>Example 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Link 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    border:1px solid black;
}
.menu, .menu li {
    padding:0;
    margin:0 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu ul {
    display:none;
}
.menu li:hover ul  {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
     padding:0;
}
.menu li:hover ul li {
    margin:0 0;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.menu li ul li:hover {
    background-color:skyblue;

}
```

Comment: I actually need to use jQuery because the html gets generated. So I need to find a way to do it with jQuery.

Comment: If u are generating your menu dynamically then why you strictly need jquery solution?

Comment: I don't strictly need it, but I can't select some of the id's which are generated, with the CSS-selectors.

Comment: You can still use css with dynamically created html elements. just generate them with a class instead of an id if you plan on needing to create more than one. https://jsfiddle.net/cshanno/bgryLLwo/2/