# Make a dropdown menu with jQuery and children selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I just made a dropdown menu with jQuery.
This is how my structure looks like.
[image]
And this is the jsFiddle, which was created: https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/10/
Currently, it shows the whole pnlSubmenu, but it should only show the submenu_link 1-5 if I hover over the first child of the pnlMenu.

This is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('.menu_link').ready(function () {
               $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
           });
           $('.menu_link').hover(function () {
               $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").slideDown(200);
           });
           $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').mouseenter( function () {
               $(this).show();
           });
           $('[id$=pnlSubmenu]').mouseleave(function () {
               $(this).hide();
           });
           $('.menu_link').mouseleave(function () {
               $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").hide();
           });
       });
```

And this is my ASP.NET code:

```
<nav id="menu">

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlMenu" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubmenu" runat="server">

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


            </asp:Panel>
        </nav>
```

Can i do this with the nth-child anyhow?
I tried something like that, but nothing happened.

```
 $("[id$=pnlMenu]").children(1).hover(function () {
               $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").children(1).slideDown(200);
           });
```

Comment: Please avoid asking the same question you previously have.. Instead you should wait for an answer or place a bounty on it [Dropdown menu with jQuery and nth-child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32073651/dropdown-menu-with-jquery-and-nth-child). By you changing some of the wording doesn't mean it's a different question at all

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the bounty tip, didn't know you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of element, using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/), then [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method can be used.

```
$("[id$=pnlMenu]").children().hover(function () {
    var index = $("[id$=pnlMenu]").index(this); //Get the index
    $("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").children().eq(index).slideDown(200);

    //You can also use :eq()
    //$("[id$=pnlSubmenu]").children(":eq(" + index + ")").slideDown(200);
});
```

*Note: index is zero-based*

Comment: Can you show me how where to put it, because it's not working yet. https://jsfiddle.net/rxLg0bo4/12/